# Fade out mouse cursor when inactive (with jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouse-cursor

I have an element with class `fade-object` that fades out when the mouse is inactive for a certain amount of time (5000 milliseconds in this case), and fades back in when the mouse is moved again.

This is the code I'm using:

```
       var timer;
        $(document).mousemove(function() {
            if (timer) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = 0;
            }

            $('.fade-object').fadeIn();
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                $('.fade-object').fadeOut()
            }, 5000)
        })
```

How do I make it so the mouse cursor fades in and out the same way, in sync with my `fade-object` div?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set `cursor: none` in the CSS of the `html` and prevent the `mousemove` event that occurs directly after a `fadeout` from re-displaying the item.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qLvDD/1/)

```
$(function () {
    var timer;
    var fadeInBuffer = false;
    $(document).mousemove(function () {
        if (!fadeInBuffer) {
            if (timer) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = 0;
            }
            $('.fade-object').fadeIn();
            $('html').css({
                cursor: ''
            });
        } else {
            fadeInBuffer = false;
        }


        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $('.fade-object').fadeOut()
            $('html').css({
                cursor: 'none'
            });
            fadeInBuffer = true;
        }, 5000)
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for some reason...the div with .fade-object fades right back in after fading out.

Comment: Updated - For some reason, it seems that the `fadeout` causes `mousemove` to fire.  So I just have a one call buffer that ignores the next `mousemove` after a `fadeout`.

Comment: Wow, thank you! That is weird about mousemove firing. For some reason the cursor still isn't disappearing for me, even in the fiddle. Is it just a support thing? I'm using the latest version of Safari.

Comment: I noticed that too..I changed it to change `html` instead of `body`. And it seems to work for me.

Comment: There maybe some issues with this on various browsers.  Use this link to test. http://jsfiddle.net/qLvDD/1/embedded/result/

Comment: You might use a transparent png instead of `none` to achieve cross-browser support. http://icelab.com.au/articles/invisible-cursors-in-google-chrome-with-css/

Answer (score 7):

Apply `cursor: none` via jQuery with a delay. Don't think it's possible to make it fade out.

The use of this css property is limited to Firefox 3+, Safari 5+, and Chrome 5+.
It's not supported in IE (as stated [here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/)).

I've put an example at [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/unuhaj/8), in my browser it's not working (Firefox 19.0.2 on linux), test it with as many browser as you can :)

Anyway I can't recommend such a technique, it's never a good idea to hide something from the user that's not part of your UI, if you think about it the mouse cursor is part of the operative system UI.