# CSS hide cursor without firing JavaScript mousemove event

Tags: javascript, css, event-handling, preventdefault

Trying to hide the cusor in a video container along with some controls. I have a small JavaScript function that adds a class to the container on `mousemove` to show the controls and I looped in some css for `cursor: none;`. It successfully hides the cursor, but apparently that css change also triggers the `mousemove` event, so I have an endless loop of starting to fade out and fading right back in.

**TLDR;** how can I prevent the css cursor change from firing the `mousemove` event?

- [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/UXtFj/2/)
- Also worth mentioning, [I've seen this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532423/fade-out-mouse-cursor-when-inactive-with-jquery), but don't understand how they're avoiding the event though it does work.

JavaScript

```
$bod.on('mousemove', '.vidCont', function(){

    var thiis = $(this),
        time  = thiis.data('timer'),
        newTime;

    if (time){

        clearTimeout(time);
    }

    thiis.addClass('showControls');

    newTime = setTimeout(function(){

        thiis.removeClass('showControls');

    }, 2000);

    thiis.data('timer', newTime);
});
```

Comment: I hear that you don't understand that other SO question's solution. Why don't you just use it anyway?

Comment: In the other answer, it sets a flag `fadeInBuffer` to true when you fate out.  Then the first call to mousemove sets that flag to false, and then any subsequent call to mousemove does the fade in.  Does that make sense now?

Comment: In other words, the event is still called every time, it just skips over the work that the event would normally do when the flag is set.

Comment: @LeeMeador too verbose.

Comment: @TimGoodman thank you- will post my working answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @timgoodman explained, it was a matter of applying the same buffer flag as the previous SO post. The difference in my answer is the scope of the css and mouse event. I'm also using classes for my css changes and combining variables because I'm a boyscout.

- [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/UXtFj/3/)

  ```
  $('body').on('mousemove', '.cont', function(){

      var thiis  = $(this),
          time   = thiis.data('timer'),
          buffer = thiis.data('buffer'),
          newTime;

      if (!buffer){

          if (time){

              clearTimeout(time);
          }

          thiis.addClass('showControls');

          newTime = setTimeout(function(){

              thiis.removeClass('showControls');

              thiis.data('buffer', true);
          }, 2000);
      } else {

          thiis.data('buffer', false);
      }

      thiis.data('timer', newTime);
  });
  ```